# Instagram Api OAuthAccessTokenException 400 error

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, google-maps, instagram

I am having an issue with my Rails 4.0 web app. I am using Google maps Api to return the lat and long then passing that info to Instagram's Api. However I am getting an error:

`{"meta":{"error_type":"OAuthAccessTokenException","code":400,"error_message":"The access_token provided is invalid."}}`

I have gone through the process of creating multiple AccessTokens but still nothing.

Has anyone run into this before and if so how did you solve it?

This is my code:

```
var codeAddressLat;
var codeAddressLng;
var addMarkerLat;
var addMarkerLng;
var locationLat;
var locationLong;
var accessToken;
var mediaEndPoint;

$(document).ready(function(){


var accessToken="USER_ACCESSTOKEN_PLACEHOLDER";
$('.get_photo').click(function(){
    mediaEndPoint = ("https://api.instagram.com/v1/media/search?lat=" +  locationLat + "&lng=" + locationLong + "&access_token=" + accessToken + "?callback=?");

    if (addMarkerLng !== null  &&  addMarkerLat !== null ) {
        locationLong=addMarkerLng;
        locationLat=addMarkerLat;
        console.log("Add Marker " + mediaEndPoint)
    }else if (codeAddressLat !== null && codeAddressLng !== null) {
        locationLat=codeAddressLat;
        locationLong=codeAddressLng;
        console.log("Code Address: "+ mediaEndPoint)
    }else{
        alert("Oops! Something went wrong, please try again!")
    }
    $(".insta-list").empty();

    $.getJSON(mediaEndPoint, function(jsonResult){

        var items = jsonResult["data"];
        var container =[]
        $.each(items, function(){
        var val = this["images"]["standard_resolution"]["url"]
        container.push("<img src=" + val + ">" );

    });
        $("<ul/>",{
            "class": "insta-list",
            html: imageContanier.join( "" )
        }).appendTo(".modal-body");
    })

});
});
```

Comment: Your access token has expired, you need to get a new one.

Comment: What Kevin said, also you shouldn't be storing your access token here. Put it in your .env instead.

Comment: @KevinBrown I have replaced my accessToken and still run into the same issue...

Answer (score 1):

I have solved this issue.

Turns out the reason I was getting the error:
`{"meta":{"error_type":"OAuthAccessTokenException","code":400,"error_message":"The access_token provided is invalid."}}`

Was because the variable I created that held the Instagram API Media End Point had a syntax issue.

I had added "?callback=?" to bypass the XMLHttpRequest errors ([CORS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-origin_resource_sharing)). When in fact the callback syntax should of been "&callback=?".